# need wordpress admins that cannot delete each other

Tags: wordpress, admin, administrator

I have a wordpress with one admin. (This is not a multi-site)
I need two add another admin. I realized that one admin can delete the other's profile.

I need to know how to add two admins that can delete their account by themselves, but cannot delete the other's account without their consent.

Answer (score 1):

Try by using "user role editor" plugin. Make sure that you are the only who can use this plugin and delete other users.